# Discord.py play music isnt playing but joins

Tags: python, discord.py

So my bot joins and searches for songs just fine. However, it does not play anything. The error i get on the console is this:

Ignoring exception in command play:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Richard Ille\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Richard Ille\Desktop\Folders\Yota Inc discord bot\cogs\music3.py", line 94, in play
self.start_playing(ctx.voice_client, player)
File "C:\Users\Richard Ille\Desktop\Folders\Yota Inc discord bot\cogs\music3.py", line 108, in start_playing
self.queue[0] = player
IndexError: list assignment index out of range

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Richard Ille\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
File "C:\Users\Richard Ille\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Richard Ille\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: IndexError: list assignment index out of range

And here is the code i have:

```
@commands.command()
    async def play(self, ctx, *, url):

        #try:

        async with ctx.typing():
            player = await YTDLSource.from_url(url, loop=self.bot.loop, stream=True)

            if len(self.queue) == 0:

                self.start_playing(ctx.voice_client, player)
                await ctx.send(f':mag_right: **Searching for** ``' + url + '``\n**Now Playing:** ``{}'.format(player.title) + "``")

            else:
                    
                self.queue[len(self.queue)] = player
                await ctx.send(f':mag_right: **Searching for** ``' + url + '``\n**Added to queue:** ``{}'.format(player.title) + "``")

        #except:

        #await ctx.send("Somenthing went wrong - please try again later!")

    def start_playing(self, voice_client, player):

        self.queue[0] = player

        i = 0
        while i <  len(self.queue):
            try:
                voice_client.play(self.queue[i], after=lambda e: print('Player error: %s' % e) if e else None)

            except:
                pass
            i += 1
```

Comment: Do you have FFMPEG installed? It's needed for this to work.

Comment: yes ffmpeg is installed and i followed the steps to do it correctly, it just doesnt play any audio

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand much about what you are trying to say, but the error message clearly says that the problem is in `self.queue[0] = player`. As the `if` statement guarantees, `self.queue` is empty, therefore trying to get an index raises `IndexError`.

Besides, in the `else` block, you cannot get `self.queue[len(self.queue)]`, as the last index would be `len(self.queue)-1`

Comment: the bot will join the voice channel, but not play audio. When a user speaks, their name lights up green - the bot does the same thing, but no audio is heard. if i add a -1 would that fix it?

Comment: Well, the error you showed states `IndexError`, which has to do with the indexing I pointed above